# как остановить многопоточность thread python

Tags: python, многопоточность, requests, threading

Для курсовой нужно было осуществить brute-forc, код полностью работает, но хотелось бы как-то остановить потоки по нормальному после нахождения пароля, а не через os._exit(1). Также пробовал через Lock и Rlock останавливает только поток, в котором нашелся пароль.

```
import string
import os
from itertools import *
import requests
from threading import *
from queue import Queue
THREAD_NUM = 20
ALPHABET = [ch for ch in (string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)]
server = "http://192.168.255.255:2512/auth"
def check_auntification(passQueue:Queue):

        while not passQueue.empty():
            password = passQueue.get()

            try:

                req = requests.post(server, json = {"login": "v7", "password": password})
                print(password)

                if req.status_code == 200:
                    print(password, "ПАРОЛЬ НАЙДЕН")
                    os._exit(1)

            except:
                print(password)
                pass
bruteQueue = Queue()
n = 4
for i in range(n):
    for probablyPass in product(ALPHABET, repeat = i):
        strPass = "".join(probablyPass)
        bruteQueue.put(strPass)

for i in range(THREAD_NUM):
    th = Thread(target = check_auntification, args=(bruteQueue,))
    th.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность остановить созданные потоки, вам нужно сохранить их в список *(или любой другой контейнер)*.

Добавьте в начало вашей программы инициализацию пустого списка `thread_list = []`. И при запуске каждого потока добавляйте его в список:

```
for i in range(THREAD_NUM):
    th = Thread(target = check_auntification, args=(bruteQueue,))
    thread_list.append(th)
    th.start()
```

### UPDATE.

---

Отвечая на ваш вопрос для корректного завершения потоков теперь можно написать функцию `kill_all_threads()` и при нахождении пароля вызывать ее, а не `os.exit`:

```
def kill_all_threads():
   for thread in thread_list:
      thread.join(0)
```

`thread.join(0)` нужен для того, чтобы поток завершался немедленно, а не ожидал завершения выполнения.

Также потребуется "примитив синхронизации", самое легкое решение это использование глобальной переменной *(с помощью нее будем останавливать дальнейшие вычисления, если пароль уже найден)*, измените тело вашей функции `check_auntification` как показано ниже:

```python
 def check_auntification(passQueue: Queue):
    global pwd_found
    pwd_found = False
    while not passQueue.empty() and not pwd_found:
```

Вызов функции `kill_all_threads()` следует осуществлять в новом потоке, т.к. остановить текущий поток из его же контекста нельзя.

```python
if req.status_code == 200:
   pwd_found = True
   print(password, "ПАРОЛЬ НАЙДЕН")
   close_thread = Thread(target=kill_all_threads)
   close_thread.start()
   close_thread.join()
```

Comment: не сработало, дальше искал пароли, или я что-то не понял

Comment: @OPEX обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо работает